# Infinite product include summation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

I would like to find an infinite product of$$\prod _{n=2}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{a_n}\right)$$

where $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{n!(-1)^{k-1}}{k!} $

I tried to compute $a_2 , a_3 ,...$, but nothing pattern can see.

Any ideas?

Comment: The product appears to converge to $1-e^{-1}=.6321205588$. Now to find a proof....

Comment: @ByronSchmuland How do you just say that it is going to converge to $1-1/e$

Comment: @Gem I calculated the first few terms with a computer, and noticed that it looks close to $1-1/e$. Then Ron Gordon found a proof in his answer below.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland ok, I thought there was some kind of technique you used.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that, because

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = \frac{a_n}{n!} + \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n!}$$

the given sequence satisfies

$$a_{n+1} = (n+1) (a_n + (-1)^{n-1}) $$

Then

$$1+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{a_n} = \frac{a_n+(-1)^{n-1}}{a_n} = \frac1{n+1} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

Then

$$\prod_{n=2}^N \left (1+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{a_n} \right ) = \frac{2}{(N+1)!} \frac{a_{N+1}}{a_2} = \frac{a_{N+1}}{(N+1)!}$$

The product sought is just the limit of this ratio as $N \to \infty$, which is just

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k!} = 1-\frac1{e} $$